# Core Plot Different Plot Symbols in single Plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

Is it possible to have different symbols for different points in a single plot. I tried changing the symbolforscatterPlot-recordIndex method providing symbols when wanted and nil in other cases but it does not work; hence the doubt.

Comment: That's the right method. Please provide your code so we can see the details and help troubleshoot.

Comment: Solved it.Thanks Eric. The problem was that while returning the symbolforscatterplot for particular point I was setting the plot symbol to that particular symbol;  hence for the rest of the points though I was returning nil from the method the symbol was plotted that was set. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Hi,Eric. Now I have data coming at real time and being plotted accordingly using InsertatIndex method .Is it possible to highlight only the last added symbol.

Comment: Sure. Just reload the data point for any that you want to change. You can use the `-reloadPlotSymbolsInIndexRange:` method to update the plot symbols only without changing the data values.

Comment: Works. Thanks Eric.